# Load and Run Random Scripts using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, jquery-mobile

I want to know how can I use a script similar like this which rotates the script. My knowledge of jQuery is close to Zero

This loads random images.

```
<div id="result"></div>
<script>    
var imageURLs = [
        "http://www.myserver.com/images/image1.png",
        "http://www.myserver.com/images/image2.png",
        "http://www.myserver.com/images/image3.png"
    ];

    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    var $img = $("<img/>", {
        src: imageURLs[randomIndex],
        alt: 'Some Text'
    });

    $("#result").empty().append($img);

</script>
```

**I am having trouble to use this method for < script > tag.**

Can any one please help me. Advance Thanks.

---

This code which I am currently works but it uses **document.write**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var imageURLs = [
    "http://www.samplescript.com/1.js",
    "http://www.samplescript.com/2.js"
  ];
  function getImageTag() {
    var img = '<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src=\"';
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageURLs.length);
    img += imageURLs[randomIndex];
    img += '\" />';
    return img;
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write(getImageTag());
</script>
```

I am not a fan of document.write.

**

### Want to have the similar kind of functionality without document.write.

**

Comment: Can you show what you've tried to use it for a script tag?

Comment: you should show what have you tried and have problems, no a working example without issues?

Comment: @Popnoodles tried to change the <img/> to <script/>. Did not work.

Comment: Have you tried using the library function [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)?

Comment: Here is how you load scripts with jquery http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/